# Track some files in git, but only in one local copy

Tags: git

I have a changing/developing program that generates some results for a paper that I need to keep as they change with the program's changes. These results can be rather large and aren't something I want to push to a remote for various reasons (don't want to monkey with git lfs and file hosting, don't want to force collaborators to download it on clone, could conflict with collaborators' local results, don't want to permanently bloat the history size, etc). Note that these results are 1. not deterministic and 2. take a bonkers long time to generate, so it's not just a matter of "can't you just rerun the code?"

While I could obviously just do

```
mkdir ../results/
cp -r results ../results/results-some-description
```

Having these files tracked by git has some advantages I'd like:

- It ties the results I commit to the specific window of code that generated them. I could track this information manually by putting the commit in, e.g., a README or other metadata, but having it checked in is much easier.
- It gives me the power of `git log` to easily view what the state of things was when I generated some version of the results.
- I only have to keep one visible copy around and don't have to have a huge folder with a dozen directories that I need to grep through to find what state I need (not to mention cross-referencing commits etc).

I've considered a couple methods but thrown them out for various reasons:

#### 1. Create a purely local repository, add remote at appropriate commit as submodule or subtree of some sort

This feels like a few too many steps every time I generate results (albeit perhaps a scriptable set of steps), as well as being a bit fragile if I forget one. I feel like may as well just back them up in individual folders if I'm going to do this.

#### 2. Make a local branch I never push that contains the results files; merge working branch at the time I'm ready to commit new results

I thought this was promising until I really thought about it, and it's easiest to illustrate with the following set of commands:

```
> mkdir tmp && cd tmp
> git init
> touch foo
> git add foo
> git commit -m "Add foo"
> touch result
> git checkout -b results
> git add result
> git commit -m "Add results"
> git checkout foo
> echo "new stuff" >> results
> git checkout results
```

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        results
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Oh... well, um... that's right, oops. They can't even be stashed because they're not tracked in the working branch.

---

Really what I feel like I want is some sort of (Github compatible) hook that basically says "ignore this directory subtree entirely as if it wasn't in history at all, but only on push/pull to/from remote." Honestly, it's not even a big deal if it pushes spooky phantom empty commits when the only files touched were files in that set, or blows up comically if a collaborator commits conflicting files. Though, it would be ideal if I had the ability to push files in that tree if I *really* wanted to (to, e.g. snapshot a window of code+results and tag to share in the future).

Is there any way to manage something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can imagine is similar to your local branch solution, but with a small change: each time you want to commit results, create a `results.description` or `results.serial-number` branch in which you commit your results. As you described, these branches will never get pushed to the server.

This solves the conflict with the untracked file: you don't checkout `results.1` to create `results.2`, so Git will not be aware of it or flag any conflicts.

```
#update and commit software 
run-experiment > results
git checkout -b results.1
git add results
git commit -m "results and maybe comments about it"
git checkout master
# update and commit software
run-experiment > results
git checkout -b results.2
git add results
git commit -m "results and maybe comments about it"
git checkout master
```

To enumerate all the results in your sandbox:

```
git branch | grep results
```

To review some old results:

```
git checkout results.1
```

To review some old results without checking the branch out:

```
git show results.1:results
```

Now, I noticed in your question you're doing `echo "new stuff" >> results`, suggesting you want the results file to be cumulative. My solution does not do that, but here's a way to inspect all the results as if the file was cumulative:

```
for branch in `git branch | grep results`; do
   echo ======================== $branch
   git show $branch:results
done | less
```

Comment: The `echo` was just to illustrate the file changing, it's not really cumulative.